# Get top N elements, but if N+1 is equal to N, return the N+1 as well

Tags: php, arrays

I have associative array as follows:

```
array(
    [random_key_1] => 30,
    [random_key_2] => 27,
    [random_key_3] => 25,
    [random_key_4] => 25,
    [random_key_5] => 25,
    [random_key_6] => 22,
);
```

The array is already sorted and I don't know key names. I would like to get top 3 elements. But simple:

```
array_slice($array, 0, 3);
```

would not work in my case because the fourth and the fifth element should be returned as well.

Is there any built-in function or maybe I should write it from scratch? I reckon this should be some recursive function to check consecutive elements.

Comment: Recursion is for nested elements. You have a flat structure, which is better suited for iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want to do.
Get the top elements values, and then intersect them with the array to preserve the keys.

```
// gets the unique top 3 values
$top_values = array_slice(array_unique($array), 0, 3);
// intersects the original array with the top 3 values
$top_values_with_keys_and_duplicates = array_intersect($array, $top_values);
```

Comment: Wow, your solution is even better, let me accept your answer instead. Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to grab the top three, then iterate over the rest, checking if the next element is equal to the last. If it is, grab it, otherwise stop iteration.

Something like this should work:

```
$top = array_slice($array, 0, 3);
foreach( array_slice( $array, 4) as $el) {
    if( $el === $top[2]) {
        $top[] = $el;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Note you could also just use the array pointers with `reset()`, `current()` and `next()` to grab the top 3, then continue iterating until the current element doesn't equal the last element.

Comment: If the key should be kept, you can use `foreach( array_slice( $array, 4) as $key=>$el)` and `$top[$key] = $el`

Comment: @MartyMcVry - True, but you need the `$preserve_keys` parameter to be set to `true` for both calls into `array_slice()`, otherwise as written it will always reindex the array numerically starting at `0`.

Comment: Maybe that's not what he wants. If the array is something like `array(1, 2, 2, 3, 4)`, `$top` is then equal to `(1 2 2)` while it should be `(1 2 2 3)`

Comment: Yes, I would like to preserve keys.